# Browsing C (m.2 drive) drive and i hear my backup drive of 4tb spinning and c: looks slow

Tags: windows, ssd, performance, windows-explorer, m.2

My computer is new, most of the parts are from 2018 including new motherboard, new everything and the oldest part is a gtx 980ti.
it uses a 500gb M.2 drive that has more than 60% free.
d: is a 240gb SSD i just use it for dropbox
e is a normal drive of 500gb used only as steam library
f: is a backup drive in raid 1 with 4tb (4tb+4tb)

f: is my backup drive, windows backups up stuff on this drive from time to time like the recover previous version of files and all that.

when i browse c:\ for example to upload a file using filezilla, it takes some time like 1 to 2 seconds, like im accessing my NAS or a normal HDD, and i hear one of the hdd's probably F: spinning.
is this related to windows using the big drive for backups ? my windows feels slow because of this. any way to fix it or do i buy another m.2 drive just for backups ?

ps: my samsung m.2 is working fine, a quick benchmark here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hphc7.png)

system specs:
i7-8700k (watercooled and temps are fine, i checked)
32GB GDDR4 ram
motherboard
asus prime Z370-A
Geforce GTX 980ti

The pc is fast, really fast, but managing lots of files or browsing c: looks slow, i have some problems refreshing big directories wich takes a lot of time sometimes and i have deleted the windows explorer history from time to time wich makes it fast again.

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer (which is used in the "open file" dialog boxes) is not the best of all pieces of software ever written: It accesses lots of storage places when it is counterintuitive to do so.

E.g. every time it touches "This Computer" or "Libraries", it touches all disks, that are visible there to update usage stats etc. - even network locations (as evidenced by the network activity).

I am not aware of a way to avoid this less than unmounting the devices in question.

Comment: i also have mapped a z: drive wich has a wdmycloud that is not the fastest nas systems in the world. maybe this also makes it slow ?

Comment: Could easily be - AFAIK there is nothing you can do about it short of unmapping Z:

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here but i think that i found the solution to my problem and this might be helpful to more people. After researching a lot about this i found some problems with my windows.
Having all the programs updated was half te battle, i found that windows was using pagefiles on the SSD drives, not sure why but maybe using third party software to try and optimize it made it worse. Disabling the pagefiles alone made the entire system feel a lot better. on a pc with 1 nvmi drive 2 ssd's and 2 normal drives and 32gb of ram the pagefile was really a bad idea and made the entire system VERY slow, disabling it made the trick.

The rest:
I found that intel rapid storage was in fact not updated, i downloaded intel driver update tool that found that it was outdated, i made the update and also found another problem, i was not using cache on my 4tb RAID1, i enabled it and added the option just for READ instead of read and write to be on the safe side. another reboot and another speed incrementation.

Playing around with the system performance when looking at the pagefile options i found that after clicking on performance on the first tab, i did not had let windows decide the best for the computer option and had all the checkboxes enabled, including making previews for the status bar and all that, i selected let windows decide and on the last reboot noticed another performance gain.
im now going to use the computer for a few days and see if after a few days of uptime and hard work the problems are gone. for now, looks like they are really gone.